# Unable to access BIOS after enabling secure boot (no screen output)

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, gpu, secure-boot

I disabled CSM and enabled secure boot on my Gigabyte Aorus b550 AC with a EVGA GTX 1080.

Every time I boot up my machine, it boots straight into Windows (dual-boot system with ReFind as bootloader) without prompting me with a BIOS flash screen.

If I try to enter the BIOS (spam the <kbd>delete</kbd> key right after pressing the power button), my machine powers up (LED lights, fan spin, everything) but there's no video output. I have 2 displays connected with DisplayPort.

I only found a temporary fix, which is to reset the BIOS and keep CSM enabled. This allows me to enter the BIOS again but doesn't enable secure boot.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me Gigabyte Aorus b550.

##### To fix the no video output/blank screen issue:

To my knowledge, this only works for 10-series cards (maybe also older models, don't know).

1. Boot into windows and install this [tool from Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/). The program will test your GPU and install firmware on your GPU, so it supports DisplayPort version 1.3 and 1.4.
2. Turn your machine off and try to enter the BIOS again, everything should work now.

Some of you will probably have other issues by now, like "Invalid signature detected". If you want to resolve this, do the following:

1. Go into the BIOS and go into advanced settings.
2. From the menu bar on top, select boot.
3. Click on secure boot (pretty much at the bottom).
4. Change secure boot mode to custom.
5. Click on restore factory keys and confirm.
6. Reboot back into the BIOS and secure boot should now show active.
7. Change secure boot mode back to standard (not necessary, but I did it anyway).

If the link is dead, Google for "Nvidia DisplayPort firmware update".